# How to call main method of a Scala program from the main method of a java program?

Tags: java, scala

Suppose I have a Scala class and a Java class in a Java project and the scala class is like below

```
class Sam {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
  }

}
```

How can I call it's main method from the main method of a java program which is present in the same project

Comment: Isn't `new Sam().main(javaArgs)` inside Java's main working?

Comment: Consider extending the `App` trait.

Comment: Yes, consider App. But don't consider Application, which is deprecated.

Comment: Actually, don't consider `App` either.  Until `App` gets rid of the `DelayedInit` behavior, you'll wonder why your fields aren't initialized.  See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/29133161/169947 .

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Typically, main methods are `static` in Java, and in an `object` in Scala. This allows you to run them from the command line.  Your code defines a `class`, not an `object`.

I'd suggest changing your Scala code to:

```
object Sam {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println("Hello")
  }
}
```

You can then call this from your Java main method as follows:

```
class Foo  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sam.main(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: I extracted the project into a jar file and tried to call the Foo class from command line. But, it's not working!

Comment: There are several reasons why that might not work. For example, if the classpath was not set correctly (you'd probably see a ClassNotFoundException); or if the class name specified on the command line is incorrect ("Could not find or load main class"). I assume "extracted the project into a jar" refers to an IDE feature, so I guess there might be a problem there too. Perhaps open a new question with a more detailed description?