# Scala class decleration

Tags: class, scala

I have used Scala but I worked with objects but now I have to use classes. I am creating a scala class in a package, however, when I try to run it, it asks me to choose between Scala Applet or Scala Application and none of them work. Anybody has an idea on how to fix this problem? And do you declare a main method inside a class (like in objects) ?

Comment: Check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16673919/how-to-call-main-method-of-a-scala-program-from-the-main-method-of-a-java-progra

Comment: In addition to the answers below, also just run your apps at the command line at first. It side-steps having to also learn the IDE's finnicky nature... and the less things you hav eto learn simultaneously, the more quickly you can learn them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For running your application you need to have App extended object or an object with main method.
It is nice that you are using classes. But the entry point of your code must be an object with main method or ( App extended )

So use your classes to build the application but start your application from an object.

Comment: can you give me an example please? Because I did not understand the concept

Comment: you can have some classes as:
class A

class B extends A

object Program extends App {
    new A()
    new B()
/* start of your application */

}

Answer (score 1):

```
case class Test(val x: Int);

object Main extends App {
   override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
      val x = Test(5);
      println("this is the main method");
      println(x);
   }
}
```

In the JVM world, the main method in the entry point to an application.
In general, the main method is where you start your various components, the threads/executors that run them etc.