# Scala member field visibility in Spark jobs

Tags: scala, initialization, apache-spark, visibility

I have a Scala class that I define like so:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}

object TestObject extends App{
  val FAMILY = "data".toUpperCase

  override def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val sc = new SparkContext(new SparkConf())

    sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
      .map(getData)
      .saveAsTextFile("my_output")
  }

  def getData(i: Int) = {
    ( i, FAMILY, "data".toUpperCase )
  }
}
```

I submit it to a YARN cluster like so:

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf spark-submit \
    --conf spark.hadoop.validateOutputSpecs=false \
    --conf spark.yarn.jar=hdfs:/apps/local/spark-assembly-1.2.1-hadoop2.4.0.jar \
    --deploy-mode=cluster \
    --master=yarn \
    --class=TestObject \
    target/scala-2.11/myjar-assembly-1.1.jar
```

Unexpectedly, the output looks like the following, indicating that the `getData` method can't see the value of `FAMILY`:

```
(1,null,DATA)
(2,null,DATA)
(3,null,DATA)
(4,null,DATA)
(5,null,DATA)
(6,null,DATA)
(7,null,DATA)
(8,null,DATA)
(9,null,DATA)
(10,null,DATA)
```

What do I need to understand, about fields and scoping and visibility and spark submission and objects and singletons and whatnot, to understand why this is happening?  And what should I be doing instead, if I basically want variables defined as "constants" visible to the `getData` method?

Comment: This is a serialization issue and it looks like you are using Kryo as serialization. Are you providing the correct class registration?  Have you tried removing the `spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer` line?

Comment: Do I need any Kryo registration if I'm not using custom types in my RDDs?

Comment: I have removed the Kryo line from the job submission, and the same problem still happens.

Comment: I edited the code to make it a lot simpler, removing all the HBase stuff since that's not part of the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I don't think you should be defining a `main` method.  When you extend `App`, [you inherit a `main`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.6/src/library/scala/App.scala), and you should not override it since that is what actually invokes the code in your `App`.

For example, the simple class in your answer should be written

```
object TestObject extends App {
  val FAMILY = "data"
  println(FAMILY, "data")
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Figured it out.  It's the `App` trait causing trouble.  It manifests even in this simple class:

```
object TestObject extends App {
  val FAMILY = "data"
  override def main(args: Array[String]) = println(FAMILY, "data")
}
# prints "(null,data)"
```

Apparently `App` [inherits from `DelayedInit`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.6/#scala.App), which means that when `main()` runs, `FAMILY` hasn't been initialized.  Exactly what I don't want, so I'm going to stop using `App`.

Comment: Ken, I think you've misunderstood how App works.  You don't extend App and also define a main; you extend App *in lieu of* defining a main.  When  you extend App, you *inherit* a main, and that main calls the code in your App, which was saved off as a function by the compiler.

Comment: You're right.  That seems to avoid the initialization timing problem, I'll accept your answer.